# How to declare a function using assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my code. Every time I try to compile it, it gives me this error 
 ***expected primary-expression before 'float' at line 3***

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
auto fun = (float x){
    return 1/(1-x);
};
int main(){
    auto x=fun(0.5);
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have got lambdas and functions mixed up. If you just remove that `=` it should work - as long as you have C++14 enabled.

Comment: While there is an answer to your question (see answers below), what problem are you trying to solve that isn't better solved by the idiomatic way declaring a function using a function declaration?

Answer (score 1):

With the assignment operator (i.e., `=`) I can think of a lambda instead of a function:

```
auto fun = [](float x){
    return 1/(1-x);
};
```

That is, just by adding empty square brackets (i.e., `[]`, which corresponds to the lambda [capture list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture)) before the parameter list, turns the code following the `=` into a lambda expression.

Technically, the `=` above isn't really the assignment operator. It just belongs to the syntax of [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
auto fun = [](float x){
    return 1/(1-x);
};
```